# Is there a way to check the validity of a password only if 3/4 conditions are met?

Tags: python, passwords

I have to make a program to check the validity of a password.
Conditions are: at least 8 characters, 1 upper letter, 1 lower letter, 1 number in range 0-9, 1 symbol.
If 3 / 4 of the conditions are met (excluding password length because it should always be longer than 8 characters) the program should check the password strength.
If the length of the password is 8 characters long the strength is equal to 1. for every 4 more characters the strength increases by 1.
In case all conditions are met, the strength should be doubled.

In the code bellow, I wrote a huge line of code but I think I have a mistake and that there is a much faster way to do it.
So I am asking you whether there is a way to do it faster or not. If yes, what would that be?

```
def is_valid_password():
    pwd=input("Enter a password: ")
    f=1
    l=0
    u=0
    d=0
    s=0
    p=0
    if(len(pwd)>=8):
        for i in pwd:
            if i.islower():
                l+=1
            if i.isupper():
                u+=1
            if i.isdigit():
                d+=1
            if(i=='!' or i=='@' or i=='#' or i=='$' or i=='&' or i=='_'):
                s+=1
    if((l+u+d+s)==len(pwd) and l==0 and u>=1 and d>=1 and s>=1) or ((l+u+d+s)==len(pwd) and l>=1 and u==0 and d>=1 and s>=1) or ((l+u+d+s)==len(pwd) and l>=1 and u>=1 and d==0 and s>=1) or ((l+u+d+s)==len(pwd) and l>=1 and u>=1 and d>=1 and s==0) or ((l+u+d+s)==len(pwd) and l>=1 and u>=1 and d>=1 and s>=1):
        if((l+u+d+s)==len(pwd) and l>=1 and u>=1 and d>=1 and s>=1):
            if(len(pwd)>12):
                f=(f+(len(pwd)-8)//4)*2
            elif(len(pwd)>=9 and len(pwd)<=12):
                f==4
            elif(len(pwd)==8):
                f==2
            print(f"Valid password with strength {f}")        
        else:
            if(len(pwd)>12):
                f=f+(len(pwd)-8)//4
            elif(len(pwd)>=9 and len(pwd)<=12):
                f==2
            elif(len(pwd)==8):
                f==1
            print(f"Valid password with strength {f}")
            
    else:
        print("Invalid password!")
 
while True:
    is_valid_password()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this way using regex.
include what you need to find in brackets and in or in the pattern:

```
passwd='P%&ippo8lo'
pattern=r'(\d)|([[:upper:]])|([[:lower:]])|([\$%&])'
```

1-digit, 2-uppercase letter, 3-lowercase letter, 4-simbol

the 'findall' method will return a list of sets in which you just have to make sure that all the fields have been used:

```
rt=regex.findall(pattern, passwd)
[
 ('', 'P', '', '')
 ('', '', '', '%')
 ('', '', '', '&')
 ('', '', 'i', '')
 ('', '', 'p', '')
 ('', '', 'p', '')
 ('', '', 'o', '')
 ('8', '', '', '')
 ('', '', 'l', '')
 ('', '', 'o', '')
]
```

now the hardness of the password depends on how many fields of the set have been used:

```
good = [False] * 4

for s in rt:
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        if s[i] != '':
            good[i] = True

print(good)

[True, True, True, True]
```

if one of the requests has not been used, the corresponding field will be False

About the password length:

```
ovr_len = len(password) - 8
hardness_point = int(ovr_len / 4)
total_point += hardness_point
```

one point every 4 characters beyond 8

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably make a list of functions like `testLength()`, `testUpper()`, `testDigit()`, and so on. The functions just return a 1 (fulfilled) or 0 (failed). Note that it is really easy to extend the number and kind of tests.

Now you write something like

```
numPassed = testLength(pwd) + \
            testUpper(pwd) + \
            testDigit(pwd) + ...
if (numPassed < (3 * numTests)/4)
    issueError("password too weak")
```

This is kind of pseudo code, but I think the idea is understandable.
Note that this code certainly isn't faster, but it is easy to understand and easy to maintain or extend. (It's not slow either, as long as you don't want to test a billion passwords at once).

Comment: Thanks for responding. In this particular case I don't mind whether the program is fast or not so I will give it a shot.

Comment: In this line "if (numPassed < (3 * numTests)/4)" what is numTests ?

Comment: @DnsStratos I didn't define `numPassed` in my code excerpt, but it should contain what it says: the total number of tests you are going to perform. In your case that would be 4, if I've counted correctly

Comment: Oh oh i see. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I do this:

```
import re
from math import ceil

def is_valid_password(PassWord):
    Conditions = 0
    
    if len(PassWord) < 8:
        print(f"The password ({PassWord}) is too short !")
        return 0
    
    # Or re.findall("[a-z]", PassWord):
    if PassWord != PassWord.lower():
        Conditions += 1
    
    # Or re.findall("[A-Z]", PassWord):
    if PassWord != PassWord.upper():
        Conditions += 1
    
    if re.findall("[0-9]", PassWord):
        Conditions += 1
    
    # Or re.findall("[!@#$&_]", PassWord):
    if re.findall("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", PassWord):
        Conditions += 1
    
    if Conditions < 3:
        print(f"The password ({PassWord}) not respect the conditions !")
        return 0
    
    # Or Power = 1 + ceil((len(PassWord) - 8) / 4) 
    # if you want :
    # 8 char = 1
    # 9-12 char = 2
    # 13-16 char = 3
    Power = 1 + int((len(PassWord) - 8) / 4)
    
    if Conditions == 4:
        Power *= 2
    
    print(f"Valid password ({PassWord}) with strength {Power}") 
    return 1


is_valid_password("Hello") # Error
is_valid_password("hello2020") # Error
is_valid_password("HELLO2020") # Error
is_valid_password("Hello2022") # 1
is_valid_password("Hello 2022") # 2
is_valid_password("HelloHello2022") # 2
is_valid_password("Hello _ 2022") # 4
is_valid_password("Hello Hello 2022") # 6
```

I guess it's simpler and more readeable.

Comment: it is but there is one mimor probelm about the power. If the length is between the values 9-11 it wont increase by 1. so for example the strength of T$st12345 is going to be 2 instead of 4. I hope i explained that well

Comment: When you say "8 characters long the strength is equal to 1. for every 4 more characters the strength increases by 1", I understand: - 
8-11 = 1 # There isn't 4 more characters... - 
12-15 = 2 # There is 4 more characters... - 

If you want 2 for 9 characters: - 
`from math import ceil`
`Power = 1 + ceil((len(PassWord) - 8) / 4)`